# PHP keep form info after submit form failed

Tags: php, forms, submit

Hello 
I am building a form in a mvc system view, and i want that all the inserted values will be kept,in case of form submit failure.
How can this be done: i tried like (example for a field):

```
     <label for="user_firstname">Nume</label>
    <input id="user_firstname" type="text" name="user_firstname" value=<?= $_POST['user_firstmane'] ?> >
    <? if (isset($errors['user_firstname'])): ?>
    <span class="error"><?= $errors['user_firstname']; ?></span>
<? endif; ?>
```

but of course, it doesn't work the first time (when no post action is done).

what is the simplest way to do this? any ideas?

thank you

Comment: What do you mean by this? "but of course, it doesn't work the first time" .... the first time the form is displayed to the user the value cannot be there since he hasn't submitted anything yet. Or is there some php error?

Comment: 1) Why do you say 'it doesn't work the first time?'  2) You mispelled $_POST['user_firstmane'], should be $_POST['user_firstname'] of course, 3) (little OT) In my opinion to be much more "MVC" you shouldn't use the $_POST variable directly but a value taken from the "controller" (eg, a "User" object with "firstName" property) would be  a better choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest something like:

```
<label for="user_firstname">Nume</label>
    <input id="user_firstname" type="text" name="user_firstname" value=<?(isset($_POST['user_firstname']) ? $_POST['user_firstname'] : ""; ?>>
    <? if (isset($errors['user_firstname'])): ?>
    <span class="error"><?= $errors['user_firstname']; ?></span>
<? endif; ?>
```

You also had a typo in the $_POST["user_firstmane"] should be $_POST["user_firstname"] :)

Comment: It worth a comment that in order to acomplish this you can't do a POST/Redirect/GET pattern when the submission **fail**.

Answer (score 2):

Just loop through the DOM in javascript and put the PHP $_POST data into the input.value

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

<?php
    echo "var jsArray = new Array();";
    foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value){
        echo "jsArray['$key'] = '$value';";  //turn it into a javascript array
    }
?>


        // Grab all elements that have tagname input
        var inputArr = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

        // Loop through those elements and fill in data
        for (var i = 0; i < inputArr.length; i++){
            inputArr[i].value = jsArray[inputArr[i].name];

        }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
value="<?php echo isset($_POST['user_firstname'])? $_POST['user_firstname'] : "" ?>"
```

Comment: shouldnt you change "" to ''?

Answer (score 1):

You mean you want to keep the value of the form when it failed to submit? You can use $_SESSION to store the value in the check page. For example:

check.php

```
<?php
   session_start();
   if (strlen($_POST['user_firstname']) < 5) { //for example
       $_SESSION['user_firstname'] = $_POST['user_firstname'];
   }
?>
```

In your current form. change `value=<?= $_POST['user_firstmane'] ?>` to `value="<?=$_SESSION['user_firstname']?>"`, so:

```
<label for="user_firstname">Nume</label>
    <input id="user_firstname" type="text" name="user_firstname" value="<?=$_SESSION['user_firstname']?>" />
    <? if (isset($errors['user_firstname'])): ?>
    <span class="error"><?= $errors['user_firstname']; ?></span>
<? endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="FirstName" name="FirstName" placeholder="First name" title="First Name" required="" tabindex="1" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['FirstName'])){ echo htmlentities($_POST['FirstName']);}?>"/>
```

This code is much more easier to keep form info after submit form failed.