# resubmit the form in php

Tags: php, html, forms

I need to know the information when i fill the form and then submit it. If error occurs with the help of header function in php it loads the same form page but all filled data lost why .

I need those filled data for resubmit the form.

I need it for php.
 thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225617/php-keep-form-info-after-submit-form-failed  

Same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$form_name    = !empty($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : "";
$form_email   = !empty($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : "";
$form_error   = "";

if($form_name == "" OR $form_email == ""){
   $form_error = "<p>Error huh!</p>";
}
else{
   header("Location: http://yours.com/where.php");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this

```
<?php
    function get_value( $key ){
        if ( isset( $_POST[ $key ] ) ){ return $_POST[ $key ]; }
        return '';
    }
?>

<form method="POST" action="">
    <input name="field-1" value="<?php echo get_value('field-1'); ?>" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the text value of the html

```
    <?php if ( isset ( $_POST['field1'])) {
        echo $field1 ;
        }  
     ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look here. It's a small tutorial on what you're trying to do: http://www.coursesweb.net/php-mysql/data-form-fields-after-submit_t

Answer (score 0):

Submit the form on the same page and use `@$_POST['field']` for field value.

and put such a code on the top of this page

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  if(!error){
    redirect to any page
  }
}
```